# Usar sesión en vez de cookies para evitar duplicado de likes

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

¿Cómo puedo remplazar la cookie por una sesión iniciada por medio de una validación para que no haya duplicado de likes, y que cuando se
inicie desde otros dispositivo permanezca el like y no permitir volver a dar like si ya se le dio?

Éste es el código de perfil del usuario.

```
  session_start(); 
  session_id();
   
   $varsession = $_SESSION['user_id'];
   
   if ($varsession == null || $varsession = '') { 
   header("Location:login.php");  die(); }
   
     require 'database.php';
   
     if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
       $records = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM datosusuarios 
        WHERE id = :id");
   
       $records->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
       $records->execute();
       $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   
       $user = null;
   
       if (count($results) > 0) {
         $user = $results;
       }   }
   
   if(!empty($user)): 
   

 $res=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC");?>
<?php 
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            
        $likeClass="far";   
        if(isset($_COOKIE['like_'.$row['id']])){
            $likeClass="fas";
        }       

        $dislikeClass="far";    
        if(isset($_COOKIE['dislike_'.$row['id']])){
            $dislikeClass="fas";
        }   
   
    else:   
    endif;
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué no utilizas para eso la propia base de datos? Creando una clave única `UNIQUE(id_usuario,id_publicacion)` te quedaría resuelto :)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal planteada la solución al problema, lo que deberías de hacer es crear una tabla en la base de datos (asumo que no la tienes) y los campos que contengan los like lleven una validación en la que no se pueda repetir los like por usuario, te plantearé un escenario:

Supongamos que tenemos ciertos productos y los queremos ordenar por cantidad de likes, pero queremos que un usuario solo de like una vez a cada producto, entonces para ello, podríamos tener (crear) una tabla likes (por ponerle un nombre) y contendría los siguientes campos (te simulare la tabla en MYSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE likes(
likes_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
usuarios_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
productos_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(likes_id),
// AQUI LA MAGIA CON LA RESTRICCIÓN
UNIQUE INDEX `NombreRestricción` (`usuarios_id`, `productos_id`),
// LAS RELACIONES EXTERNAS
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(usuarios_id) REFERENCES usuarios(usuarios_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(productos_id) REFERENCES productos(productos_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
);
```

Como puedes ver directamente en la creación de la tabla a través de la restricción de índice único:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `NombreRestricción` (`usuarios_id`, `productos_id`),
```

Lo que hacemos es restringir a una única vez el like por usuario y producto, así un usuario le puede dar like a miles de productos pero no repetir, un producto puede recibir miles de likes pero un mismo usuario solo le podrá dar like una vez y con ese planteamiento solucionas tu problema, solo te faltaría almacenar en la base de datos el like del usuario, trabajar con la usabilidad de la web y mandar un mensaje o simplemente desactivar el like para todos aquellos productos a los que ya les dio like el usuario logueado y listo, problema resuelto...

Espero te sirva como guía mi respuesta, saludos